# C++ decltype failed on vector elem

Tags: c++, decltype

```cpp
template <typename T>
void F(T&) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

template <typename T>
void F(vector<T>&) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    F<decltype(x)>(x);      // this line compile and works fine
    
    vector<int> v;
    F<decltype(v[0])>(v);                       // this line won't compile
    F<remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>>(v);     // Neither this one
}
```

Why wouldn't `F<decltype(v[0])>(v);` work?

Comment: Why bother calling it like that anyway? Also, what is `v[0]`? You want to say `int`, but you'd be wrong. Because `v[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: @sweenish Using `v[0]` is UB, but shouldn't it be runtime error instead of compile time?

Comment: Using `v[0]` inside of `decltype` is evaluated at compile-time. It is not actually accessing the 1st vector element, it is merely deducing the type that `v[0]` is declared to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, <del>you do not have a `v[0]`. Even if you do have elements in `v`,</del>* `decltype(v[0])` will be `int&`, hence `F<decltype(v[0])>(v)` fails.

<sup>Note*: more in the comment about why having elements in `v` or not doesn't matter.</sup>

---

Second, `remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>` is the name of a `struct`, not a type. To properly get the type from it, you should call:

```cpp
std::remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>::type
                                     ^^^^^^
```

Or:

```cpp
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(v[0])>
                     ^^
```

---

Also, instead of using `remove_reference`, you can simply get the element type of a vector with `::value_type`:

```cpp
F<decltype(v)::value_type>(v);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aG9GKoK91)

Comment: "you do not have a v[0]" -- that doesn't matter, it's in an unevaluated context, the decltype is the type of it if it did exist. Otherwise, solid answer.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Thank you for the correction, edited accordingly.

Comment: Even if you could fix the compiler error, why not just let the compiler deduce the template for you? You don't need to pass the template parameter explicitly. Use `template <typename T, typename... Ts> void F(vector<T, Ts...>&) { ... }` and then call `F(v);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau F<decltype(v[0])::type>(v); will save me some typing when I change the type of v[0].

Comment: @Ranoiaetep thanks for explanations and I like this one "F<decltype(v)::value_type>(v);"

Comment: @haifengyang `decltype(v[0])::type` will not work when `v[0]` is just an`int`. In any case, using the template I showed you will save you even more time and typing on the long run, since you won't have to worry about wasting time figuring out what to type in the template parameter at all, because your can just omit it completely at the call site